# can the union of regular languages be non-Context-Free

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

I came across the following statement which is supposedly true:

> There exists an infinite set of regular languages, such that their union is not a CFL

it is explained this way:
we'll define $L_k = \{ 0^k1^k0^k \}$

$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} 
$
$ L_i = \left\{ 0^k1^k0^k \mid k \geq 1 \right\}
$

so that each language in the union only contains one string and therefore - regular,
but their union is equivalent to: $0^n1^n0^n$ which is not CF.

on the other hand regular languages are closed under union, which means it'd be easy to prove inductively that the above union = regular language,
since it consists only of regular languages.

and all regular languages are CF.

isn't that a contradiction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it’s not a contradiction, by induction you can only prove a *finite* union of regular languages is regular, it tells you nothing about whether or not an infinite union is always regular.

Comment: @Skynet No. Induction is used to prove statements on *every element* of one specific infinite set: $\Bbb N$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, *every* language $L$ on a finite alphabet is a countable union of regular languages. Just observe that all finite languages are regular and that
$$
L = \bigcup_{u \in L}\ \{u\}
$$
Now, you can choose for $L$ not only a non-context-free language, but a non-context-sensitive or a non-recursively enumerable one if you wish.